Prove $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2| x_1\geq 0, x_2\geq x_1^3\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex

Prove that $$A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2| x_1\geq 0, x_2\geq
 x_1^3\}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$$ is a convex set

My attempt:
Let $x=(x_1,x_2)$, $y=(y_1,y_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then we must show that for any $t\in [0,1]$,(a) $z_1 = tx_1 + (1-t)y_1 \geq 0$ and (b) $z_2 = tx_2 + (1-t)y_2 \geq z_1^3$.
(a) is obvious since $t, x_1, 1-t, $ and $y_1$ are all $\geq 0$
What I'm stuck at is part b). I need to prove $$tx_2 + (1-t)y_2 \geq (tx_1 + (1-t)y_1)^3$$
with $x_1,y_1\geq 0, x_2\geq x_1^3, y_2\geq y_1^3$. 
I don't know how to prove this inequality. I've been trying to "multiply out", but it seems in vain. Could someone have better way to prove this inequality? Thanks in advance!

From the assumption that $(x_{1}, x_{2}), (y_{1}, y_{2}) \in A$, we know that $x_{2} \geq x_{1}^{3}$, $y_{2} \geq y_{1}^{3}$. Therefore we have
$$tx_{2} + (1-t)y_{2} \geq tx_{1}^{3} + (1-t)y_{1}^{3}.$$ So it suffices to show
$$tx_{1}^{3} + (1-t)y_{1}^{3} \geq (tx_{1} + (1-t)y_{1})^{3}$$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$, $x_{1}, y_{1} \geq 0$.
This is exactly the claim that the function $f(x) = x^{3}$ is convex on $[0, \infty)$, which you can show by computing the second derivative.

Set $A$ is the epigraph of function $f(x) = x^3$ over $[0,\infty)$. Since $f(x)$ is convex in the domain, so is the epigraph.
